# for loop to while loop

Tags: java, loops

I am using a `for` loop to print the backwards alphabet in uppercase but I would like to know how to do the same thing with a `while` loop, which I am not very good with.

```
String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqstuvwxyz";      
int x = 0;

for(x = alphabet.length() - 1; x > -1; x--) {
  System.out.print(alphabet.charAt(x));
  System.out.print(alphabet.toUpperCase());                 
}
```

I also need to terminate it when it reaches A. think it's something like this, but I don't know how to make it loop backwards. I'd really appreciate your help!

```
while(alphabet.length() < 26) {
  System.out.print(alphabet.charAt(x));  
  System.out.print(alphabet.toUpperCase());     
  if(x == A) {
    break;
  }     
}
```

Comment: "for(A; B; C) { body; }" is equivalent to "A; while(B) { body; C; }"

Comment: @ignis You should add that an answer :).

Comment: The while(alphabet.length()<26) {} loop will never terminate.

Comment: @ignis that would be the answer.

Comment: ... And there's no need to iterate over a string (as long as you want the english alphabet): start with char c = 'Z', and while c >='A', print and then decrement c. You can do it in a single 'for' statement.

Comment: @ignis Is there a special reason why you are adding it as comment and not answer?

Answer (score 4):

```
for (initialization; condition; increment) {

}
```

is same as:

```
{
    initialization;
    while(condition) {
       // body
       increment;
    }
}
```

The outer block creates a `block` scope for the initialized parameter, that we get in a for loop also. But, if you are declaring your `for-loop` variable outside the loop, then you can omit that outer block.

Now you can map your for loop to the while loop.

Comment: @user1707517. Yeah. both the loops work exactly in the same way with some modification in structure. :)

Comment: I would also place second code in outer block like `{ initialization; while(condition) { body; increment;} }` since variables declared in `initialization` wont be accessible after that block.

Comment: @Pshemo. Ah! true. nice catch. Will add it. :) +1 on it.

Comment: The translation is not so simple if there are `continue`s in the loop. In the `for` loop, a `continue` jumps to the `increment` code, in the `while` loop that would be skipped. Not sure what the best way to treat that is, without `goto`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  char[] alphabet =  "abcdefghijklmnopqstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
  int index = alphabet.length - 1;

  while (index >= 0) {
    System.out.println(alphabet[index--]);
  }
}
```

This is a most efficient solution with minimal memory overhead.

Answer (score 2):

There is a much simpler way to reverse a string in Java.

```
public class StringReversalExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqstuvwxyz";
      String reversedString = new StringBuilder(alphabet).reverse().toString();
      System.out.println(reversedString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = alphabet.length() - 1;
while( x > -1 )
    {
        System.out.print(  alphabet.charAt( x ));  
        System.out.print( alphabet.toUpperCase() );
        x--;
    }
```