# Loop that keeps printing each increasing result

Tags: java, loops

I want the program to keep track of the sum of every positive integer until 100 like:
The sum of positive integers from 1 to 1 is 1
The sum of positive integers from 1 to 2 is 3...
The sum of positive integers from 1 to 100 is 5050

I would prefer to use a while loop if possible, no arrays or anything fancy since I am not that advanced yet.

Editing this code with a while loop and keeping track of the 100 results would be perfect

```
public class SumNatural {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num = 100, sum = 0;

        for(int i = 1; i <= num; ++i) {
            // sum = sum + i;
            sum += i;
        }

        System.out.println("Sum of positive integers from... " + "is " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe reading this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102142/for-loop-to-while-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the `System.out.println` statement inside the loop to make your `for` work:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= num; ++i) {
    System.out.println("Sum of positive integers from 1 to " + i + " is " + (sum += i));
}
```

For a `while` statement, you will be needed a variable declared outside the loop. That variable, let's say `i`, should be incremented at the very end of the `while` block.

```
int i = 1;
while (i <= num) {
    System.out.println("Sum of positive integers from 1 to " + i + " is " + (sum += i++));
}
```

For readability, you might want to use `String.format`:

```
System.out.format("Sum of positive integers from 1 to %d is %d\n", i, sum += i++);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was so easy and compact, and thanks for teaching me the format option, is just like in python,i didnt know

Answer (score 0):

This would be the answer to the question

```
public class HelloWorld{
     public static void main(String []args){
        int num = 100, sum = 0, i=1;

        while(i<=num)   {
            sum += i;
            System.out.println("Sum of positive integers from... " +i+ "is " + sum);
            i++;
        }

     }
}
```

Here the `i` is initialized at the starting and `i++` is increasing the value of `i` until the while condition fails (similar to for loop)

Comment: that works but i needed to keep printing each one increasingly until it reaches 100